# How to convert row rdd to typed rdd

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, parquet, apache-spark-dataset

Is it possible to convert a Row RDD to Typed RDD. In code below, can I convert row JavaRDD to Counter type JavaRDD

code :

```
JavaRDD<Counter> rdd = sc.parallelize(counters);
Dataset<Counter> ds = sqlContext.createDataset(rdd.rdd(), encoder);

DataFrame df = ds.toDF();
df.show()

df.write().parquet(path);
DataFrame newDataDF = sqlContext.read().parquet(path);

newDataDF.toJavaRDD(); // This gives a row type rdd
```

In Scala :

```
case class A(countId: Long, bytes: Array[Byte], blist: List[B])
case class B(id: String, count: Long)

val b1 = B("a", 1L)
val b2 = B("b", 2L)

val a1 = A(1L, Array(1.toByte,2.toByte), List(a1, a2))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(a1))

val dataSet: Dataset[A] = sqlContext.createDataset(rdd)
val df = dataSet.toDF()

 // this shows, so this last entry is for List[B] in which it is storing string as null
 |1|[01 02]| [[null,3984726108...|]
 df.show

df.write.parquet(path)
val roundTripRDD = sqlContext.read.parquet(path).as[A].rdd

//throws error here when run show on df
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java',
Line 300, Column 68: 
No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters 
"long, byte[], scala.collection.Seq"; candidates are:
"test.data.A(long, byte[], scala.collection.immutable.List)"


roundTripRDD.toDF.show

assertEquals(roundTripRDD, rdd)
```

DO I need to provide some kind of constructor for case class?

Comment: You have to use toJavaRDD in the Dataset, not in the Dataframe.

Comment: I didn't get that , what do you mean?

Comment: DataFrame to toJavaRDD() you will get JavaRDD<Row> but if you have Dataset<Counter> toJavaRDD you will get JavaRDD<Counter>

Comment: oh ok. I changed my code to reflect that and I was able to get it working in scala. I tried to get it working in scala as well but its not working. Any idea what am I missing there ?

the line that I mentioned is throwing errors 

**sqlContext.read.parquet(path).as[A].show**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sqlContext.read().parquet(path).as(encoder).rdd().toJavaRDD();
```

Comment: sqlContext.read().parquet(path).as(encoder).rdd().toJavaRDD();

Comment: LostInOverflow: Does writing the similar code in scala needs to include anything else , I have updated the question to reflect the scala code ?

Comment: I tried that , I think the problem is with the case class, it is showing this schema when I try to print it in the console

**Updated the question**